# Multi Tenancy Multiple Client Multiple Database, One Source Code - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, multi-tenant, multiple-databases

I have a task to create an existing project to multi tenancy, as the application has many clients so we decided to do this.

We have merged our source code to work with any database, all source code are same for all client.

Now, earlier the database connection has happened using one config file includes in each script.

but, as you know the source is now having multiple client which databases are different, we are stuck to manage the DB with the client.

Intially,

http://localhost/workspace/client/ --> this is a URL given to client, now I redirect this to index.php using htaccess and based on client/ I knew which client this package is going to use.

there are different clients,
http://localhost/workspace/clien1/
http://localhost/workspace/clien2/
http://localhost/workspace/client3/

and so on..

Now, in **index.php** page redirect to login.php, but the config is not set for the DB as per the client.

if anyone handled this, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you make the redirection to `login.php` in your `index.php` you should either set a cookie or a session variable specifying which DB config should be used for this particular client. Then `login.php` can read the cookie/session variable and set the relevant DB config.

Comment: Hi GELOV, Thanks for your answer. I have chosen SESSION above COOKIE in this case, having, it is partially working. having one more doubt any specific length on storing session on any web app? or having thousands of session started at a time will affect the performance of the application? what will be the best practice in this cases?

Comment: Since the sessions are stored on the server - this concentrates the load. The actual load will depend on how you store your sessions (on the filesystem, through the `igbinary` PHP extension, in a relational database, in Redis, etc.) If you use cookies - you do not have to store anything on the server because the cookie contains (in encrypted form) the user ID and the expiration time. Every request to your server will receive an updated cookie with new expiration time - so that you can force re-login if you receive a cookie with expired time.

Answer (score 3):

The database connection parameters (server address, db username / password, and database name) are, in your proposed setup,  attributes of your users or your customers (your users' organizations).

I guess you will authenticate your users by looking them up in a common database and then verifying passwords with [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) When you know you have a valid user you can

- retrieve the db connection parameters from your user database
- store them in [php session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)
- use php's secure session cookie scheme to leave your user's browser with a way to identify the appropriate session.
- after redirection, or on subsequent web requests, open the db mentioned in the session variables

Make sure the cookie you place doesn't contain the database parameters embedded in it, or a cybercriminal will figure out how to change the cookie to gain unauthorized access.

But, **Pro tip:** Creating a new database for every customer is famously unscalable. What happens if

- your project is successful and you find yourself adding a thousand new customers some day? You will have to add a thousand databases that day.
- you have 500 active sessions at some moment? Each of them will have its own dbms connection, making php's connection pooling schemes useless. Connection pooling is vital to good web application performance.
- you have a need to perform some reporting operation that covers all customers? You'll have to run the reports for each customer separately and figure out how to merge them together in your report program. That is difficult.

A good practice for multitenant online applications is to put customer id or user id values on each data record, and use query clauses like `WHERE customer_id = ?` (current customer) to separate data user by user.

Hopefully it is not too late to revisit your design decision to use multiple databases.

Comment: Hi O.Jones, Thanks for your valuable response. your guess was not correct. we do not have a common database to verify the user. instead of that, based on the URL we decide which customer he is and set the database connection in the session. and that work.
I will discuss this answer with my team and see what we decide.